# How do I make notifications that don't get saved?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

Some scripts I wrote show notifications like "*Volume up*" or "*Reset brightness*" for example, using `notify-send`. However, the notifications get saved in the notification menu on Ubuntu 18.04, which I don't want since there are so many repeats. How do I prevent that?

---

Here's what I tried:

- Checked `man notify-send` but didn't see any options about not saving the notification.
- `notify-send --urgency=low` - no difference
- Researched "gnome toast notifications" but apparently they're application-specific, which doesn't work for me
- Considered using Zenity but I couldn't find a way to make a notification that doesn't steal focus.
- In Python, making a `Notify.notification` object `.show()` twice - no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send a transient notification with `notify-send` using the `-h` (hint) option like this:

```
notify-send -h int:transient:1 "Hello" "World"
```

Hints are a way to provide extra data to a notification server that the server may be able to make use of. From `man notify-send`

```
-h, --hint=TYPE:NAME:VALUE
       Specifies basic extra data to pass. Valid types are int, double, string and byte.
```

[Check this out](https://developer.gnome.org/notification-spec/#hints) (external link to developer.gnome.org) for some standard hints. The `transient` hint is described as follows:

> When set the server will treat the notification as transient and by-pass the server's persistence capability, if it should exist.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted! Though I just noticed I still have some noisy notifications from Clementine. Would you know anything making Clementine's notifications transient? I'll probably open a new question about it.

Comment: Or maybe I'll just disable Clementine notifications... I'll get back to you. But I found this btw if you're curious: https://askubuntu.com/a/109133/301745